# Qt M/V Deligate

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, delegates, mv

I want to show `QDateTimeWidget` when user selects the `QTableView` cell (Which contains datetime). I have written delegate. How can I know column type of using model index dynamically in delegate create editor method?

Comment: You can check cell data returned type. Remember that index.data(Qt::ItemRole) returns QVariant

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you create your own delegate by subclassing `QStyledItemDelegate`, in your function

```
QWidget *DateDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
                                const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                const QModelIndex &index) const
```

you can use `index`.

So, you can get row or column by using `index.row(), index.column()`. To get text (your date) you can do something like this:

```
QString tmpStr =
        index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
```

Good luck!